# @SequenceGenerator on class annotated with @MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, sequence-generators

I have following structure of my entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqGenerator")
  private Long id;
}

@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqGenerator", sequenceName = "DICTIONARY_SEQ")
public abstract class Intermed extends BaseEntity {}

@Entity
public class MyEntity1 extends Intermed {}

@Entity
public class MyEntity2 extends Intermed {}
```

And I got following exception:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [context/applicationContext.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: seqGenerator
```

When I change @MappedSuperclass to @Entity on Intermed class, everything works OK. 
Are there any problems with using @MappedSuperclass and @SequenceGenerator? Or I have missed something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is what the JPA 1.0 spec says about the `SequenceGenerator` annotation:

> #### 9.1.37 SequenceGenerator Annotation
>
> The `SequenceGenerator` annotation
>   defines a primary key generator that
>   may be referenced by name when a
>   generator element is specified for the
>   `GeneratedValue` annotation. A
>   sequence generator may be specified
>   **on the entity class** or **on the primary key field or property**. The
>   scope of the generator name is global
>   to the persistence unit (across all
>   generator types).

And a mapped superclass is not an entity. So according to the way I read the spec, what you want to do is not possible. Either make the `Intermed` class an entity or put the `SequenceGenerator` on the sub classes.

Comment: the JPA 2.0 is talking about the same thing

Comment: @glaz666 Hehe :) And indeed, this didn't change in the JPA 2.0 spec, same stuff.

Comment: so there is no way to define 1 single "global" sequence for several entities ?

Comment: @radai I put that on the field and it works. See Kallja's answer.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same problem described in this question while trying to achieve application wide id generators.

The solution is actually in the first answer: **put the sequence generator on the primary key field**.

Like so:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqGenerator", sequenceName = "DICTIONARY_SEQ")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqGenerator")
  private Long id;
}

@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Intermed extends BaseEntity {}

@Entity
public class MyEntity1 extends Intermed {}

@Entity
public class MyEntity2 extends Intermed {}
```

While doing things this way seems remarkably stupid (at least to me) it does work.